# ZVI Analysis Tool - unexpected results

Tags: dem

I have run the ZVI analysis tool from the perspective of an observer standing on a hill looking out   to a defined altitude.

[image: Inputs to ZVI Analysis Tool]

However, the results do not correspond to my expectation from the underlying terrain data (black dot is the location of the observer).

[image: Bare Terrain]

In the resulting coverage map there is a sharp cut off to the North East that I cannot explain. I would expect the viewer to be able to see across the valley to the east but the coverage does not match this. I have run the tool in this way for multiple other points and have not encountered this before. Does anyone have any idea what might be happening here?

[image: Coverage area with unexpected sharp cut off]